# Use pipeline DSL for freestyle jobs?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

I want to trigger a Jenkins build from Artifactory:

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plug-in#JenkinsArtifactoryPlug-in-TriggeringBuilds

So it looks like it only works with freestyle non-multibranch jobs? It's going to be kicked off by Artifactory.

I already have a shared library repo with a lot of shared functions and stuff. How can I use that code in a freestyle job? I don't want to manage this job's code in a different place.

I would be nice if I could have a freestyle job execute code from the vars folder of my shared library.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a free style job that trigger a pipeline job or a number of jobs:
[image: jenkins job build screenshot]

And in the pipeline you can use shared library functions as well.